# How does Shuffled-Complex-Evolution-Metropolis algorithm compare to other adaptive samplers (e.g. NUTS)?

Tags: optimization, markov-chain-montecarlo, algorithms, gibbs

I recently heard of the Shuffled-Complex-Evolution-Metropolis algorithm and am curious how it compares to other adaptive MCMC sampling algorithms. Unfortunately I am still learning about optimizing MCMC algorithms so I would appreciate any examples to help illustrate differences.

Comment: Could you please provide a reference as most readers will not know of this version?

Comment: It's plausible that this is very much an active area of research.